# Propagator for a $x^3$ potential in momentum space

Tags: greens-functions, propagator

Is there a way of calculating the propagator/Green's function K(p,t;p',t'), allowing me to calculate

\begin{equation}
\Psi(p,t) = \int dp' \Psi(p',t') K(p,t;p',t')
\end{equation}

of a massive particle in a $x^3$ potential? The corresponding Hamiltonian in dimensionless units would be

$H = p^2/4 + \alpha x^3$

If it is not possible to do that analytically, any ideas how to do that numerically in an efficient and stable way would be very appreciated! I am familiar with scattering matrices and transfer matrices but I fail to connect those to the Propagator. Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Assume you have explored limits in [this](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/22/21/006)?

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use the expansion of the propagator in terms of the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian (in your case it will be probably Airy functions.) While it will technically give you the exact answer, it will not be in a closed form.

As a numerical alternative, you could express this propagator as a path integral - there is much literature on how to evaluate path integrals numerically.

Note that your potential is unbounded (the energy can change from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, so the problem has many hidden pitfalls.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think that the eigenfunctions are Airy functions? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I might be wring, since I forgot that you want to do it in the momentum space. In any way, the way to go about it is write down the Schrödinger equation and then look for the special functions that solve it, in the books on the special functions, such as Gradshtein&Ryzhik orr Abramovitz&Stegun. Btw, solutions for many interesting Hamiltonians may be found in Landau&Livshitz quantum mechanics, somewhere in the problems sections.

Comment: Also: you could compute the propagator for $x$ and then convert it to momentum representation .